# How to change TextView max length?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I want to make a button which would modify the max length of a textview. I have been trying to do this or find an answer to it for hours, but I can't find anything. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public void setEditTextMaxLength(int length) {
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);
    edt_text.setFilters(FilterArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm :).